# BottomNavigationView not working with navigation

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to make this BottomNavigationView work with navigation but is giving me head-aches.

I'll explain my setup :

this the fragment of my activity_home.xml

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

Also I've tried with `FragmentContainerView` but is not working neither.

The error is on the `navigation/nav_graph.xml` as the error says :

> Exception inflating package:navigation/nav_graph line 7

Where line 7 is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/featureHomeNavGraph">

    <include //Line 7
        android:id="@+id/featureHomeNavGraph"
        app:graph="@navigation/feature_home_nav_graph"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/featureFavouritesNavGraph"
        app:graph="@navigation/feature_favourites_nav_graph" />

    ....
</navigation>
```

Then I've created different layouts for the navigations as :

feature_home_nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="package.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment" />
</navigation>
```

And feature_favourites_nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:startDestination="@id/favouritesFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/favouritesFragment"
        android:name="package.FavouritesFragment"
        android:label="FavouritesFragment" />
</navigation>
```

Then I think the problem also comes by the implementation on my `HomeActivity.kt` where I have to setup the navigation stuff... I'm doing it like this :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment?
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
            bottomNavigation,
            navHostFragment!!.navController
        )
    }
```

Also I've tried the [`NavigationExtension`](https://github.com/cdmunoz/NasaRoverPhotos/blob/bottom-nav-and-navigation-component/app/src/main/java/co/cdmunoz/nasaroverphotos/NavigationExtensions.kt) followed on this [tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/step-by-step-to-bottom-navigation-with-jetpacks-navigation-component-and-multiple-nav-graphs-271c05af1dd3) but it did not work neither.

### Note

I'm using the same id on my items of `bottom_menu.xml` than on the navigation graph id for the fragments.

Comment: What's the app's package as per the manifest?

Comment: I just removed my package, that's why it's says "package..." the package is ok

Comment: Well, me best guess so far is that `app:startDestination` in `nav_graph.xml` won't work with graphs. Try using a specific Fragment as the start destination.

Comment: But is the initialization for the bottomnavigationview correct?

Comment: I can't be sure without running the code, but it seems ok :) Anyways, what I'm trying to say is that `app:startDestination` should refer to a Fragment, not another navigation graph. As to the Bottom navigation, you might want to look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation), if haven't yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the feature_home_nav_graph doesn't have an id on the navigation tag?

Comment: I guess my problem is initialitating the BottomNavigationView, is it correct the way I'm doing the NavigationUi?